# Incorporating Volley Library on a Android Studio Project

Tags: android

I'm completely new to Android Studio and Kotlin (or Java) and I'm trying to add the Volley library.

The problem is, on the tutorial it says for me to write:
`implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'` on the gradle app file, and when I do that it appears this error:

```
Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
```

Well I've tried ChatGPT and the other tutorial on how to add a library and I can't get a hold of it, can somebody help me? Thanks!

I've tried adding the library using

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
.....
```

or

```
dependencies {
    implementation (com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0)
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
.....
```

And appears errors

Comment: could you include all of your build.gradle? it will shorten the process :)

Comment: There are two kinds of gradle build files: those written in gradle and those written in kotlin. They use different syntax because they're written in different languages.

Comment: So where do i add the text?